# Difference between $this->return and return

Tags: php, return, this

I recently came across this code in a Joomla component(Kunena, more precisely), so what is the difference between using `$this->return` VS simple `return` statement.

I already google the code, but no significant results and checked [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) & [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

I am confused with the usage of return statement with `$this` instead of simple return. Let me know if it is really simple or I am missing a childish concept, then I will surely dump the question.

Check in the code - http://pastebin.com/vvhuPhbZ

Comment: Mind posting an example? We can't take guesses at code we haven't seen...

Comment: I wouldn't think `$this->return` is even a valid statement... Unless the class has member variable `$return` that is, in which case the statement simply refers to that variable.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 sure..let me pastebin the code

Comment: @AleksG so do I ..let me show some code

Comment: `$this->return` is only a property of that object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$this->return` is not "a thing", it's simply an object property called "`return`". No difference to `$this->foo` or `$this->bar`.

`return` is *the return statement*.

Comment: It still sounds like a godawful horrible programming practice to use a keyword as a property name...

Comment: @deceze but I checked the class, no return property explicitly declared thr..check pastebin code

Comment: @aaaa "return" is a normal English word; in some context it may be the best name to describe what the property is for in the business logic domain. Say: `class Addresses { protected sender, recipient, return; }`

Comment: @swapnesh output `$this->return` and see what it says! You do not HAVE to explicitly declare a property in an object

Comment: @BenCarey yeah let me try it

Comment: @BenCarey Got it its thr..$this->return = JRequest::getInt('return', $this->catid);

Comment: @swapnesh It sounds like it is a method defined in the parent class!

Comment: @deceze Sure it is, but I'm sure there must be at least another perfectly useful name.

Comment: @aaaa Arguable, but it's not too rare that I stumble across a case where I really want to name something, say, `list`, because it really fits best. It's then pretty annoying to have to find an alternative name because `list` is a reserved word. Anyone who knows PHP knows that `$this->return` is nothing special, so it's fine IMO. (the OP being the exception that proves the rule? ^_^;;)

Comment: @deceze quite right lol with this -> "the OP being the exception that proves the rule? ^_^" :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `$this->return`. It is a property of the object you are using, much like any other property `$this->id`;

The `return` statement is used to return a value from a function. So you could effectively write:

```
return $this->return;
```

The above would return the value of `$this-<return`

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement, as you know, returns the specified value to the calling code.

`$this->return` is **not** the return statement; it is simply a property of the object which happens to be named `return`.

This would be just like a function having a variable named `$return`.

It is *possible* that the `$this->return` property may be used at some point by the class to pass data back to the calling code (it's name would imply that), but it isn't in any way related to the actual `return` statement.